# Why my Image Slider is Swipe Fast after Comeback to Activity or Fragment android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

I try to get Image from Server side and make Image Slider to swipe and Automatic Swipe Slider using Timer() ,in that Fragment my slider work perfectly but when i going to other Activity or Fragment and comeback to Slider Fragment slider goes slide fast, but i don't understand what wrong with my code . Please check my code :- **(I use Fragment)**

```
private void slider() {
    mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Pager_Adapter(getContext(), imageModelArrayList));
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    //Set circle indicator radius
    indicator.setRadius(5 * density);
    NUM_PAGES = imageModelArrayList.size();
    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    // Automatic Swip viewPager
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 3500, 3500);
    // Pager listener over indicator
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    swipeTimer.cancel();

}
```

I also put swipeTimer cancel in onDestroyView() method but it's not working for me.

Comment: Hey, I am stuck on same problem. Did you got any solution on this..?